# Convert a base 10 number to a base 3 number

Tags: java

How to convert a base 10 number to a base 3 number with a method int converter(int num).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseConverter {
    int answer;
    int cvt = 0;
    while (num >= 0) {
        int i = num / 3;
        int j = num % 3;
        String strj = Integer.toString(j);
        String strcvt = Integer.toString(cvt);
        strcvt = strj + strcvt;
        num = i;
        break;
    }
    answer = Integer.parseInt("strcvt");
    return answer;
}

public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(converter(number));
    in.close();
}
```

It was Compilation completed. But when I tried to run it, and entered a number, it showed that 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "strcvt"
I don't know how to fix it. How can I do this without using string?

Comment: Did you mean to use the variable `strcvt` in the `parseInt` method? Your code currently passes the literal string "strcvt"

Comment: What were you expecting from this line? `Integer.parseInt("strcvt");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use String at all.

Try this instead

```
public static long asBase3(int num) {
    long ret = 0, factor = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        ret += num % 3 * factor;
        num /= 3;
        factor *= 10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note: numbers in the computer are only ever N-bit i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit i.e. they are binary.  However, what you can do is create a number that when printed at base 10, will actually appear to be the number in base 3.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, `asBase3(3);` prints "1" instead of "10".

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I think you mean "factor *= 10;" instead of "factor += 10;" :)

Comment: This is weird because it doesn't return a base3 number, it returns a base 10 number that only looks like a base 3. It seems to me that if you want to *represent* it in base 3 you really ought to use a string.

Comment: @Octopus it is common to confuse/conflate the value of some data and how it is printed and not realise the difference.

Comment: It safe to use in range 0 ≤ num <= 2 ** 30. Long has 64 bits.

Answer (score 5):

"base 3 number" and "base 10 number" are the same number. In method `int converter(int num)` you're changing the number although you only need to change representation. Look at [`parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) and [`toString(int i, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-), that should help you.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot; I needed to convert a decimal (base 10) number to a ternary (base 3) number, and I was about to use one of these implementations that do that after searching on the Internet. However, using `Integer.toString(int i, int radix)` is a much easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

you are not using variable declared `String strcvt`, instead due to typo mistake you have used as `"strcvt"`

change

```
answer = Integer.parseInt("strcvt");
```

to

```
answer = Integer.parseInt(strcvt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the value of `strcvt` not the string "strcvt"

So you have to remove the double qoutes `answer = Integer.parseInt(strcvt);`
And define the variable `strcvt` outside the loop.
change you code to:

```
public static int converter(int num) {
    int answer;
    int cvt = 0;
    String strcvt = null ;
    while (num >= 0) {
        int i = num / 3;
        int j = num % 3;
        String strj = Integer.toString(j);
        strcvt = Integer.toString(cvt);
        strcvt = strj + strcvt;
        num = i;
        break;
    }
    answer = Integer.parseInt(strcvt);
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works! But the answer I got was wrong. I have to check my logic.