# Speedily calculate base 3 value of real huge integer number with Python 3

Tags: python, performance, math

We have a large number like (10**1500000)+1, and want to convert it to base 3. 
Below is running code with the fastest way we found with normal Python (without using numpy or CAS libraries).

How could the performance of base conversion (to base 3) be accelerated?

We'd like to know how this could be done in both of the following ways:

1. Using only built-in functions of Python 3 (no numpy)?
2. Using numpy (or another CAS library) from within a normal Python 3 program?

Any help is very welcome. Here is our current code:

```
#### --- Convert a huge integer to base 3 --- ####

# Convert decimal number n to a sequence of list elements
# with integer values in the range 0 to base-1.
# With divmod, it's ca. 1/3 faster than using n%b and then n//=b.
def numberToBase(n, b):
    digits = []
    while n:
        n, rem = divmod(n, b)
        digits.append(rem)
    return digits[::-1]

# Step 2: Convert given integer to another base
# With convsteps == 3, it's about 50-100 times faster than
# with with convsteps == 1, where numberToBase() is called only once.
def step2(n, b, convsteps):
    nList = []
    if convsteps == 3:  # Here the conversion is done in 3 steps
        expos = 10000, 300
        base_a = b ** expos[0]
        base_b = b ** expos[1]
        nList1 = numberToBase(n, base_a)  # time killer in this part
        nList2 = [numberToBase(ll, base_b) for ll in nList1]
        nList3 = [numberToBase(mm, b) for ll in nList2 for mm in ll]
        nList = [mm for ll in nList3 for mm in ll]
    else: # Do conversion in one bulk
        nList = numberToBase(n, b)  # that's the time killer in this part
    return nList


if __name__ == '__main__':

    int_value = (10**1500000)+1  # sample huge numbers
                          # expected begin: [2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0]
                          # expected time: 4 min with convsteps=3
    base = 3

    # Convert int_value to list of numbers of given base
    # -- two variants of step2() using different convsteps params
    numList = step2(int_value, base, convsteps=1)
    print('   3-1: numList begin:', numList[:10])

    # A value of '3' for the parameter "convsteps" makes
    # step2() much faster than a value of '1'
    numList = step2(int_value, base, convsteps=3)
    print('   3-3: numList begin:', numList[:10])
```

In [How to calculate as quick as possible the base 3 value of an integer which is given as a huge sequence of decimal digits (more than one million)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530091/how-to-calculate-as-quick-as-possible-the-base-3-value-of-an-integer-which-is-gi)
was a similar question with some more steps before the base conversion. In this question here, we concentrate on that part, which consumed by far the major part of the time, and for which we didn't get an answer yet.

Also in [Convert a base 10 number to a base 3 number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361742/convert-a-base-10-number-to-a-base-3-number), the performance aspect of HUGE numbers was not dealt with.

Comment: I wonder if `yield` would be faster than `list.append`? You also might try reversing the string instead of the list.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Thanks. Concerning reversing: I guess you mean the statement "return digits[::-1]" in the function _numberToBase(n, b)_. There is no string: The parameter "n" is an integer. Or do mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize at first that your desired output was a list rather than a string of digits. By the time I realized my mistake it was too late to edit the comment.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: No problem, your hints are welcome.  Concerning yield vs append in _numberToBase()_: Could you please show us the code how to do that?

Comment: numpy won't work for this problem because it doesn't support arbitrary precision ints

Comment: I get different results from `numberToBase(n, 3)` and `step2(n, 3, 3)` for `n = 10**30000 + 1`,  `n = 10**80000 + 1` and other large values; the answers have different lengths.  I think there is a bug in how you assemble the result in the `convsteps == 3` code, because a visual inspection of the digits at the beginning  and end of the results shows they agree.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you're right, there's a bug. If there are leading zeros in any of the intermediate results they'll get dropped.

Comment: I'd try one of the bignum library wrappers like `gmpy2`; something like `gmpy2.digits(your_num, 3)` should beat even well-designed pure Python alternatives by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @DSM, yup.  With `n = 10**1500000 + 1`,  `gmpy2.digits(n, 3)` takes about 162 milliseconds on my laptop.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: You wrote, that if there are leading zeros in any of the intermediate results, they'll get dropped. How could this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure how it could be fixed, because the structure of your loop stops when the leading digits are zero; there's no indication you need to go any further.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a method that expands on your `convsteps` solution by recursing with the base squaring with each call. Some extra work is required to remove leading zeros.

```
def number_to_base(n, b):
    if n < b:
        return [n]
    else:
        digits = [d for x in number_to_base(n, b*b) for d in divmod(x, b)]
        return digits if digits[0] else digits[1:]
```

My quick timing test shows that it's the same as your `step2` within the margin of error. But it's simpler and probably has fewer bugs.

Comment: Hey Mark, I want to see how this compares to the recursive version that I'm hacking on, but `base_recurse` is not defined. ☹️  Looks like it should just be `number_to_base`, correct?

Comment: That fixes it, and let's me know that your code is 3 - 4 times faster than mine. 


Comment: @WarrenWeckesser sorry about that, I was experimenting with a few variations and some old code got mixed in with the new. In a minute I might have an even simpler (and faster?) version.

Comment: Nice.  I improved mine, but it is still slower, and I suspect further refinements will just converge to something like your code.

Comment: @MarkRansom: For n=10**1500000+1, I compared the runtime of your _number_to_base()_ to _numberToBase()_. There is no real performance difference on my PC: Yours took 4:17 min; the _numberToBase()_ took 4:14 min.

Comment: @MarkRansom: For n=10**1500000+1, I did some more tests. Your version of _number_to_base()_ consumes the same time as _numberToBase()_ -- independently whether within _step2()_ the parameter convsteps is 1 or 3. So Mark's version is to be to preferred and there is no need for step2() any more.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I did some benchmarking and for base 10, and after ~ `n=10**1000000`, this function begins to outperform `str(n)`, which ultimately boils down to `long_to_decimal_string_internal()` that uses TAOCP, Knuth - Vol. 2 Sect. 4.4 Method 1b. This includes the time for `"".join(map(str, ... ))`. For `n=10**10000000` it is 2x as fast as the builtin conversion. Tested on Python 3.6.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: @DillonDavis: Could you please elaborate what you compared when you wrote "begins to outperform str(n)"? Where did numberToBase() or number_to_base() use a str(n)? Or is it a general remark. If so, yes, for huge integers len(str(int)) and str(int) is getting low.

Comment: @phdgroupA he was comparing `number_to_base` with a base of 10 followed by a conversion of the list to string with Python's `str(n)`. I just tried it myself with your 1.5 million digit integer and it was 8.5 seconds vs. 34.1 seconds, and both strings compared equal.

Comment: @DillonDavis you can speed up the conversion to string: `''.join('0123456789'[x] for x in seq)`. My tests with 10**1500000+1 are atypical because most of the digits are zero.

Comment: @MarkRansom I actually tested mine with '7**N' for some N that gave a value of the same order of magnitude for that exact reason.

Comment: @DillonDavis it appears Python's `str` method is O(n**2), I've both looked at the source and did some timings. I'm seriously considering submitting a patch, but I don't know how hard it will be or if it's likely to be accepted.

Comment: @MarkRansom I do think it would be worthwhile to submit a patch, or create a ticket about it at least. Beyond just being asymptotically faster, it is also a more generalizable algorithm-  the same code works for all bases, but just base 10. This would open the door for supporting other base number systems in the future.